# Tried to add Bank system using sequelize

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js, sequelize.js

I followed steps in [guide of discord.js](https://discordjs.guide/sequelize/currency.html)
I added this on my models/Users.js

```js
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
    return sequelize.define('users', {
        user_id: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING,
            primaryKey: true,
        },
        balance: {
            type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
            defaultValue: 0,
            allowNull: false,
        },
    bank: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      defaultValue: 0,
      allowNull: false,
    },
    }, {
        timestamps: false,
    });
};
```

And this to my index.js

```js
Reflect.defineProperty(client.currency, 'getBank', {
    value: function getBank(id) {
        const user = client.currency.get(id);
        return user ? user.bank : 0;
    },
});
```

I get this error:

> UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: SequelizeDatabaseError: SQLITE_ERROR: no such column: bank

Comment: That means that there isn't a column in your database called `bank`.

Comment: idk how fix it lmao

Comment: Create a column in your SQL database called `bank`.